# Google Search Console ; Products not indexing all

Tags: product, google-search-console

I'm building a smart price comparison portal and started indexing the products within the Google Search Console. I've inspected several products and requests to crawl them (as they are 'valid' products). For some reason, I see a downwards pattern of products indexed (instead of going up as I'm adding new products on a daily basis).

How does the Search Console Enhancements > Product work? Does it only add products as I query them myself or does it automatically add the products if the site is crawled again? Also, when I query older valid products they don't show up in the 'completed' items. Is it possible to get a list of already completed items?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancements are enabled by having the relevant structured data on the page. They can show up in the reports once Google has crawled the page. But the report is often just a sample of the pages Google knows with a specific type of structured data.

e.g. structured data for Googles product enhancements is defined here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product

And you can test your structured data with the [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) tool.

Comment: Thanks Tony! By any chance, do you know if it is possible to get a report of pages that are indexed with the 'product enhancements' ?

Comment: The enhancement report is your main clue. Only Google really knows what they have indexed. If a marked up page is shown in the coverage report you could assume Google has seen the markup.